# Light wavelengths and intensity at 10 m depth in coastal water

Tags: visible-light, water, wavelength, intensity

I’m planning an experiment in tanks under controlled conditions in which we’ll collect marine animals and observe their behaviours. We want to replicate to the best the light that they receive under their natural (*in situ*) conditions. The animals will be collected in coastal waters at roughly 10 m depth (approximate latitude: 49.26, and longitude: -65.74). We have a system that can adjust the photoperiod and the light intensity. However, not all light wavelengths reach 10 m depth and I’m not sure how to replicate the light coming from the moon.

Here are my questions:

**1) What are the wavelengths that should reach 10 m depth in coastal waters?**

**2) What should be the light intensity?**

**3) Is the light wavelengths coming from the moon (e.g. during a full moon) are the same than the light wavelengths coming from the sun (please explain the differences)?**

**4) Do you know of any LED lights that could replicate the light from the sun and the moon at 10 m depth in coastal water?**

Any answers or hints would be greatly appreciated!